# How to execute mvn test for Pact provider tests

Tags: java, maven, pact

I am trying to run Pact Provider tests (developed in Java) using `mvn clean test`.  It throws error after successful execution of Pact tests:

```
[TestNG] Reporter org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@40298285 failed java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.compareTo(String.java:1155)
at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter$1.compare(SuiteHTMLReporter.java:320)
```

Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
    <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-junit_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <pact.rootDir>${pact.dir}</pact.rootDir>
            <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>        
            <pact.verifier.publishResults>true</pact.verifier.publishResults>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Am I missing any additional configuration to execute Pact Provider test case from maven command?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have defined pact dir within your pom correctly like this:

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <pact.dir>${project.build.directory}/pacts</pact.dir>
  </properties>
</project>
```

I might be wrong, but I am not sure it is correct to use these properties on the provider side like you are doing here though. They are usually used on the consumer side so that the consumer can write pact files to the directory of your choosing. https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/consumer/junit5/#changing-the-directory-pact-files-are-written-to

If you want to run pact provider tests that you have in a directory, you should look into using the "au.com.dius.pact.provider" maven plugin. https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/maven#verifying-all-pact-files-in-a-directory-for-a-provider

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <serviceProviders>
        <!-- You can define as many as you need, but each must have a unique name -->
        <serviceProvider>
          <name>provider1</name>
          <!-- All the provider properties are optional, and have sensible defaults (shown below) -->
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <host>localhost</host>
          <port>8080</port>
          <path>/</path>
          <pactFileDirectory>path/to/pacts</pactFileDirectory>
        </serviceProvider>
      </serviceProviders>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The other option is to annotate your tests with the "@PactFile", "@PactUrl" or "@PactFolder" https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/junit/#example-of-http-test
It's true that this does feel similar to defining the folder as part of your system properties when running the tests, but it's not mentioned in the documentation in regards to how to load the pact contracts during pact provider verification test runs. see: https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/junit/#pact-source